# iOS not launching with xcode 6.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6.1

I'm having trouble running my app in a simulator or connected device after upgrading to xcode 6.1.

Whenever I run my app, am getting a black screen. I tried all possible solutions found online like cleaning and resetting, changing command line tool ,reinstalling ,rebooting etc...

I tried creating a new simple test project and it worked. But my older project is not launching. I even tried making my rootviewcontroller as a simple view with just background color, still its not launching.

- Is this an SDK issue?

Any help will be great,
Thanks

Comment: You have launchimages set?

Comment: yes..the app icon is coming in simulator as well as in the device..but its not launching

Comment: I occasionally get this (or what sounds like this) I just shut xcode down sometimes even restart the mac book and it works again. I think the new xcode is flakey

Comment: Have you set your "Main Interface" in the "General" tab of your target?

Comment: Have you downloaded and installed Xcode DMG on some other system and trying to use Xcode copy here?

Comment: I tried in 2 mac's tried installing from app store directly too.. no use